# Making QTableWidget editable row by row like with MS access

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtablewidget

I have subclassed QTableWidget to add some functionality. I have used the `myQTableWidgetSubclass->setRowCount(10);` method as well.

The problem is that the table is not editable. The goal is to allow the user to edit row by row, e.g. first the first row, and when that is ready (i.e. user fills the necessary data in), then the second, etc.

I would need a similar functionality to "MS access table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, this is very simple, but people will not write code for you from scratch.

1) You will need to use `void QTableWidgetItem::setFlags(Qt::ItemFlags flags)` to make items editable and non-editable. You can use this method for each item as you wish.

See the following enumeration value description from the documentation of `Qt::ItemFlags`:

> Qt::ItemIsEditable    2   It can be edited.

2) Once that is done, you need to connect your custom slot to the corresponding signal of an item that has just been edited. Your slot would then rearrange the editable feature of the cells respectively.

Here are the relevant signals that may be of interest for you:

```
* void QTableWidget::cellChanged(int row, int column) [signal]
* void QTableWidget::currentCellChanged(int currentRow, int currentColumn, int previousRow, int previousColumn) [signal]
* void QTableWidget::currentItemChanged(QTableWidgetItem * current, QTableWidgetItem * previous) [signal]
* void QTableWidget::itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem * item) [signal]
```

Then, you will need something like this:

```
connect(myQTableWidgetSubclass, SIGNAL(selectedSignalFromAbove), this, SLOT(mySlotInTheClass));

// ...

void MyClass::mySlotInTheClass(...)
{
    // ...
    myTableWidgetItemX.setFlags(...);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: so, if i have understanded perfectly,  i will insert editableitems for first row , when the user fill the entier row with data , i will insert editable item for the next row !!

Comment: @advseo32: Yes, but necessarily. You can fill the table in with many rows, but only editable items for the first, and then you start switching the editable flag according to your custom logic.

Comment: i have use this code but not working       for(int row=0; row < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col< ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); col++)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *item = NULL;


            if(row!= 0)
            {

                item = new QTableWidgetItem;

                item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,col,item);

            }else{
             item = new QTableWidgetItem;
 item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
 ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,col,item);
 }}}

Comment: Do not paste such code in a comment. Also, your abstract question has been answered. Do not change the scope when you get an answer for that. Open a new question... It is not fair that people spend time with answering a question, and then the scope is changed.

Comment: No problem, but the main issue is that you create new items as opposed to querying the existing items of the table widget. You would need to query those, and set the flags on it based on your logic.